# Access Wireless & Networks settings page

Tags: android, adb, android-settings

I am actually trying to bring up Wireless & Networks setting page using am start.

I tried all possible ways to do this and am able to open Settings page and Mobile operator settings page. But not the Wireless and Networks page (which contains *VPN*, *Airplane Mode*, *Mobile Networks*, etc..).

The way I tried opening Network operators page is as below:

```
adb shell am start -a android.settings.WIRELESS_SETTINGS -n com.android.phone/.NetworkSetting
```

Could any one help to open Wireless & Network setting page in a similar way?

Thanks in advance
Rahul

Comment: would you like to open this programmatically  ?

Comment: I updated my answer, try it! :)

Comment: yes, I am trying to open this in a JAR file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
adb shell am start -a android.settings.WIRELESS_SETTINGS
```

Edit:
To achive same result from code you can send broadcast intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent("android.settings.WIRELESS_SETTINGS");
mContext.sendBroadcast(i);
```

Edit2:
Here is the command to start it using activity name:

```
adb shell am start -n 'com.android.settings/.Settings\$WirelessSettingsActivity'
```

Depending on environment the symbol $ may or may not be escaped (remove \ before if it does not works).

Comment: I am trying to put this command in Runtime.getRuntime().exec("am start -a android.settings.WIRELESS_SETTINGS"); Is it correct?

Comment: I am doing this in a JAR file (using uiautomator). I dont have the access for 'context'.

Comment: Do you have any idea on <Package>/component equivalent for this so, I can use that with -n option. Ex: com.android.settings/.Settings  -- brings general setting page

Comment: Edited answer one more time,

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.phone/com.android.phone.NetworkSetting
```

or (better):

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.settings/com.android.settings.wifi.WifiSettings
```

**or (maybe the good one for you):**

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.phone/com.android.phone.Settings
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to open wifi settings page from code, here is an example:

```
import com.myapp.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity_layout);

        startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
    }
}
```

Comment: Starting: Intent { cmp=com.android.phone/.Settings }
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x10000000
 cmp=com.android.phone/.Settings } from null (pid=3184, uid=2000) not exported f
rom uid 1001
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerN
ative.java:1951)
        at com.android.commands.am.Am.runStart(Am.java:494)

Comment: Ok, I suppose you're using Windows 7. Try this: click Start and search for "CMD". cmd.exe is selected. Holding the CTRL key down, hit ENTER and execute CMD with Administrator privileges. Try the command now.

Comment: adb shell am start -a android.settings.WIRELESS_SETTINGS is working fine... Any idea of equivalent one with -n option?

Comment: I'm currently using the command I wrote in the answer without any problem. Seems very strange...

Comment: I'm still not sure if you intend to open the settings by command line (cmd.exe) or from your own coded app... (using intents)

Comment: I am trying to do something like this   Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell am start -a android.settings.WIRELESS_SETTINGS");

Comment: Are you coding your own JAVA app for android?

Comment: Do you know what Intents are? I update my answer, wait.

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("am start -a android.settings.WIRELESS_SETTINGS");  is working fine. Sorry I did not compile properly last time.

Comment: I am facing a problem here. When I call Runtime.getRuntime().exec("am start -a android.settings.WIRELESS_SETTINGS"); IT brings up the the page where Setting page is in instead of Wireless Settings page. This happensd only if Setting is running and there in another sub branch. How do I reset the setting page to Wireless Setting.

Comment: Or how do I kill/stop android.settings ?

Comment: Probabily you're doing something that are not allowed.. Why don't you want to close a system settings page?

Comment: I am trying to access Wireless & Networks page as asked earlier. This is is to access to Airplane mode. But, If Setting was already running, and in some other page mabe 2/3 levels down the line, The above command does not take me to Wireless & settings. So, that is the reason why I thought I'll stop/kill settings task so that when I issue the command afresh, it would bring me up the correct page.